# AdMob don't work in React-Native

Tags: react-native, admob

I was been trying use [AdMob](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob) in React-Native this last time and it doesn't work, but the same code some time ago was worked fine

Console

```
react-native init testAdmob
cd testAdmob
npm i react-native-admob -S
react-native run-android
```

Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import {AdMobBanner} from 'react-native-admob'

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Test AdMob</Text>
        <AdMobBanner
          adSize="fullBanner"
          adUnitID="ca-app-pub-9341782679724067~4969206215"
          testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
          onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
...
```

Package

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-admob": "^1.3.2"
   }
...
```

Error

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: React.Proptypes has been deprecated, check admob implementation and see if its still using, you can replace with prop-types lib or remove it.

Comment: I did check the documentation, but i don't find a useful solution yet, thanks for your time

Comment: Not the documentation, check the source code itself. This lib may be outdated

Comment: A ok, i understand, thanks you, i will do

Comment: Could you find the proptypes?

Comment: I did find, but the solution don't work for me, and i did find a new alternative, using AdMob v2